# Django no reconoce las aplicaciones : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aplicaciones'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy aprendiendo Django, me encuentro en la parte de creación de aplicaciones y tengo problemas porque al hacer `python manage.py runserver` y me manda un error con un texto grande pero que se refiere a : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aplicaciones'`.

Vi que otros usuarios tenían el mismo problema y daban una solución de modificar el archivo `apps.py`. **A continuación presento los pasos que hice para crear la aplicación**

1. Crear un proyecto django y ejecutarlo con `python manage.py runserver` (funciona correctamente).

```
proyecto_django/
    manage.py
    db.sqlite3
    proyecto_django/
        __init__.py
        asgi.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

2. Dentro de `proyecto_django/proyecto_django` creé una carpeta llamada aplicaciones y dentro agrego un archivo `__init__.py`

```
proyecto_django/
    manage.py
    db.sqlite3
    proyecto_django/
        __init__.py
        asgi.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        aplicaciones/
            __init__.py
```

3. Entro al símbolo de sistema (cmd) y me dirijo a  la dirección de `.....\proyecto_django\proyecto_django\aplicaciones>` y escribo `django-admin startapp nueva_app`.

```
proyecto_django/
    manage.py
    db.sqlite3
    proyecto_django/
        __init__.py
        asgi.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        aplicaciones/
            __init__.py
            nueva_app/
```

4. Modifiqué el archivo `settings.py`, específicamente `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'aplicaciones.nueva_app',
]
```

Abro el símbolo de sistema (cmd) me dirijo a la carpeta `....\proyecto_django>` y escribo  `python manage.py runserver`. Me devuelve el error  extenso con `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aplicaciones'`.

5. En internet encontré que debería modificar el archivo `apps.py`:

- Antes:

```py
from  django.apps  import  AppConfig
class  PruebaAppotraConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'nueva_app'
```

- Después

```py
from  django.apps  import  AppConfig
class  PruebaAppotraConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'aplicaciones.nueva_app'
```

Nuevamente abro el símbolo de sistema (cmd) me dirijo a la carpeta `....\proyecto_django>` y escribo  `python manage.py runserver`y nuevamente me devuelve el error  extenso con `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aplicaciones'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu apps.py debe de ir así:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PrimeraAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'Primer_proyecto.aplicaciones.primera_app'
```

Esto va así por la forma en que creaste tu estructura de proyecto, primera_app partiendo desde donde esta el manage.py se encuentra en Primer_proyecto/aplicaciones/primera_app

Si quieres que quede el name como 'aplicaciones.primera_app' necesitas poner tu carpeta aplicaciones al mismo nivel que donde tienes tu manage.py

También tu modelo tiene unos parámetros incorrectos en sus campos, se usa la palabra "max_length" no max_lenght

Si esto te fue de ayuda marca la respuesta como aceptada para ayudar a las demás personas que tengan este mismo problema.

Comment: me pasa igual, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Notas'.... hice los mismos pasos y no me crea la bd a menos que no ponga en el settings el nombre de la aplicacion.